# Help me with this boost::lambda::if_then expression calling a functor

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

Please have a look at the following simplified example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>

using namespace boost::lambda;
namespace bl = boost::lambda;

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    string sachNr;
    int ist;
    int soll;
};

struct Printer
{
    void operator()(const Item &item)
    {
        m_erg += item.sachNr;
    }

    operator string()
    {
        return m_erg;
    }

private:

    string m_erg;
};

void TestFunction()
{
    vector<Item> pickItems;

    string result = for_each(pickItems.begin(), pickItems.end(),   
        bl::if_then(bl::bind(&Item::ist, bl::_1) == bl::bind(&Item::soll, bl::_1), 
        Printer()));
}
```

Errormessage (gcc)

```
/TestCpp-build-desktop/../TestCpp/ctest.cpp:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘if_then(const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::relational_action<boost::lambda::equal_action>, boost::tuples::tuple<boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::action<2, boost::lambda::function_action<2, boost::lambda::detail::unspecified> >, boost::tuples::tuple<int Item::* const, const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> > >, boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::action<2, boost::lambda::function_action<2, boost::lambda::detail::unspecified> >, boost::tuples::tuple<int Item::* const, const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> > >, Printer)’
```

Any hints what's wrong with that code?

It is supposed to call the Printer functor for any item with item.soll == item.ist.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure about this particular error, but trying the alternative syntax (`if_(condition)[function]` reveals another problem: the functor to `for_each` is not `Printer` but a boost lambda object, hence you can't expect the conversion to string to happen anyway. - Since you already have written a functor, why not make it do a bit more work?

Comment: Alternatively: using BOOST_FOREACH, the code would be shorter, understandable to a layman and easier to get to work. IMO it is pointless to attempt to get `for_each` do something which it is hardly meant for.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to work with BOOST_FOREACH. That works fine.  I'm nevertheless interested in getting it done with the above example code (always trying to learn something new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ronag is correct, boost's lambda reference mentions that "They all take **lambda functors** as parameters and return void."

It seems that the alternative syntax (`bl::if_(condition)[function]`) does not require lambda functors.

However, another big problem is that `for_each` returns the functor which is a boost lambda object, not your Printer. Therefore you'll have no way to retrieve the accumulated string anyway.

You might get it to work with something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>

using namespace boost::lambda;
namespace bl = boost::lambda;

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    string sachNr;
    int ist;
    int soll;
};

struct Printer
{
    typedef void result_type;
    void operator() (const Item &item, std::string& s) const
    {
        s += item.sachNr;
    }
};

void TestFunction()
{
    vector<Item> pickItems;

    string result;
    for_each(pickItems.begin(), pickItems.end(), 
        bl::if_then(
            bl::bind(&Item::ist, bl::_1) == bl::bind(&Item::soll, bl::_1), 
            bl::bind(Printer(), bl::_1, boost::ref(result))
        )
    );
}
```

However,

```
void TestFunction()
{
    vector<Item> pickItems;
    string result;
    BOOST_FOREACH(const Item& item, pickItems) {
        if (item.ist == item.soll)
            result += item.sachNr;
    }

}
```

would be a lot simpler to get what you want. `for_each` does virtually nothing useful, so I wouldn't go out of my way to use it for nothing but trivial things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Printer printer;
 std::for_each(pickItems.begin(), pickItems.end(), bl::if_then(bl::bind(&Item::ist, bl::_1) == bl::bind(&Item::soll, bl::_1), bl::bind(&Printer::operator(), &printer, bl::_1)));
```

It seems to me that bl::if_then does not accept any functor, it needs to be a lambda_functor.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answers have already been provided. Just offering an alternative which doesn't involve a `Printer` object :

```
std::string s;
for_each(
    pickItems.begin(), pickItems.end(),
    bl::if_ (bl::bind(&Item::ist, bl::_1) == bl::bind(&Item::soll, bl::_1))
    [
        s += bl::bind(&Item::sachNr, bl::_1)
    ]
);
```